# Mount my Webserver as a drive in Win7/8

Tags: server, windows, mount

For a variety of reasons I still have a couple of Windows machines around (ver 7 and 8.1). They are still my primary machines. However, I've been running a couple of Ubuntu 12.04 desktops for a while now (9.04 before 12.04). They are my primary dev machines and they are on my LAN.

I also have a few Ubuntu 12.04 server machines serving webpages (WAN). One is my primary web server while the others house backups and DB info that has gotten large enough to require it's own server so the server serving webpages doesn't get bogged down.

Long story short, I still spend most of my time in front of my Windows machines even when doing dev for my Ubuntu machines. I grew up coding in Crimson Editor and still prefer it for my coding in PHP (and occasionally Ruby). (I know there are probably 20 better coding GUIs out there that if I just took the time to learn... suggestions are welcome.) Right now I'd like to move my dev work to an underutilized WAN server.

Crimson Editor will open files via FTP but it is a pain for several reason. Ideally I'd be able to map my WAN Ubuntu server's web directory to a drive letter on my Windows machines. Then I could use File Explorer, drag & drop, etc. natively in Windows without all the slow down and PITA of going through Crimson's FTP functionality.

My research to date suggested there were programs for doing this with Win 7 and Ubuntu 10.10 but that they were a little flacky - i.e. dropped and corrupted info. Obviously having my code dropped or corrupted in transit is less than ideal.

Is there a way to do this reliably? If so, what are security concerns? I have Iptables setup but the IP address of my home connection is dynamic not static. So I'd prefer to not have to deal with that.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the perfect opportunity to get yourself familiarized with version control software. In addition to keeping your code safe, allowing to undo things even after weeks or months, it will also solve your problem with keeping your code on a server and nevertheless being able to work on it from your favorite machine.

I personally am very fond of using [git](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_%28software%29), but there are lots of other version control systems, like [svn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Subversion) and [mercurial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercurial).

While those system differ in lots of details, the very basics are the same. You have a **local working copy** on the machine you are working on – with git, this local copy is also a full-fledged repository with the complete history, but again, details – and a (remote) **repository** with all changes ever made. Once you've finished the bit you are working on, you *commit* those changes from your local working copy to your repository. From that point in time you can delete your working copy, modify it to your liking and always return to the commited version.

At least for svn and git, there are shell extensions for the Windows Explorer that make commiting changes easy even for people completely new to this.

Comment: My main concern with this type of version control setup is that I work on the code from multiple machines. So I don't want the working copy to be local. I want it to be available to all of my machines without the need to upload it/commit it and then download to the next machine.